# Get Value of a textbox which is not in current document using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've list of slides, and in one of the slide, I have a text box with name attribute as "deals". In the next page I have a button. On clicking of that button, I want to capture the deals which were placed in the previous html. How can I capture it?

Using

```
document.getElementsByName("deals")[0].value
```

will not work, because we dont have a tag with the above name. How can I fetch it?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

P.S : I don't have access to other JS of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Though I may not have understood the question correctly (for example, I don't know how much JavaScript you may change), here are some thoughts:

1. **Solve the problem of "don't have a tag with that name"**: If the slides are on the same page, then instead of removing a DOM element,
   a `hide()` may be useful (as an implementation of changing slides).
2. **The slides are on different page of the same window**: Try utilising [Cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), if you can't change the way how the slides work.
3. **Bad Hack but should work**: Setting `window.name`.  This special "variable" will persist as long as you are in the same window (even after page changes, as long as the page doesn't re-write it).  This is some kind of a hacky way to get values across different domains (avoiding Cross Site issues...).  This should help if your slides are being imported into some other presentation sites with an `<iframe>`.

Hope the above helps!

Comment: but where do I set the cookie? I said I dont have access to other JS.

Comment: Is your JS inside an `<iframe>`? If not, you may copy the `setCookie()` and `getCookie()` from the W3CSchools Cookies link in the answer.  Then call `setCookie('deals', document.getElementsByName("deals")[0].value, 1);` before the slide changes (say, maybe listen on `onchange` event?).  When you need its value, call `getCookie('deals')`.

Comment: I know how to use cookies.. But, my concern is I dont have access to other JS. Can't I get using something window?

Comment: If your script is run directly on the page (not inside an `<iframe>`), you should have the rights to store values in the Cookies (unless the user disables it)... And in case it doesn't work, `window.name` should always be there to save some data.
As you can modify the JS, can you attach an `onchange` listener to the "deals" field so its value got saved whenever it changes?